# Different Title/Description for Google in different regions

Tags: google-search, multilingual

I have multilanguage website targeting by subdomain:

- `http://en.example.com/` - Displays only contents in English
- `http://de.example.com/` - Displays only contents in German
- ...
- `http://example.com/` - Displays contents in all languages

Title/Description are also translated depending on subdomain. Main domain is in English.
I would like to have different Title/Description on main domain `http://example.com/` for users from different region:

- `http://google.co.uk/` should display Title/Description in English
- `http://google.de/` should display Title/Description in German

My question:
For main domain `http://example.com/`, is it possible to return different Title/Description for Google bot from different regions? Or there is only one Google bot and targeting is only completed by search engine, not crawler?

Answer (score 3):

You're going about it the wrong way.

The proper way to set up a multilingual site is, as toomanyairmiles' links outline, to set up different localized subsites, either in separate directories or subdomains, e.g.

```
en.example.com / example.com/en/
de.example.com / example.com/de/
```

Google will recognize each subsite's targeted locale based on the content. However, you should also follow best practices:

- use the `Content-Language` header (or override by meta tag) and the `lang` attribute in your root element;
- [link each page to its translation](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=189077) via:
  `<link rel="alternate" hreflang="de" href="de.example.com/...">`
  `<link rel="alternate" hreflang="es" href="es.example.com/...">`
  `<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-gb" href="uk.example.com/...">`
- use a single language on each page;

Most search engines will then identify which locale each page is targeted at and the appropriate localization will be shown to searchers of each region. There's no point in having `example.com` show different language descriptions to different searchers if, when they click on it, it's always going to be English. That would be considered cloaking and is bad UX design.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm not going to display different content for different searchers, example.com will display all content and markup will be in english.

Answer (score 2):

I think you'd need a domain for each region which is locked to it's local country with google webmaster tools, but here's an article from google on how to tackle the problem.

http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2008/08/how-to-start-multilingual-site.html
http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2010/03/working-with-multilingual-websites.html

I'm not certain that the googlebot itself differentiates it's ID between countries or languages so I don't think you could target it programatically.